# Wordpress - how to migrate and keep post URLs

Tags: wordpress, migrate

I want to migrate my WP blog to a new hosting service. All the blog post URLs are plain URLs in the form *sitename.com/?p=9999*. I want to keep the same at the new hosting service. I started my blog several years ago and did not understand the difference between plain URLs and SEO-friendly URLs. Since then I have posted links to individual posts in various places and do not want those links to break. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: All In WP Migration Tool]

You can use **All In One WP migration** tool to migrate your website to another hosting.

When you use this tool it copies all the files and database into a .wpress file and you can use that same file to other hosting to import your website and because it keeps the URL structure to default ( so, your blog URLs should not change )

And if it doesn't work then you have to change the URL slug of every post and you can also use redirection.